# How to know how much a gameobject has rotated in Unity?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

So I have an object that user can rotate with touch. If needed, here is the script for it:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class SpinWithTaps : MonoBehaviour {

float lastX;
public float xDifference;
public float xDecreaseSpeed;
int xDirection = 1;

float lastY;
public float yDifference;
public float yDecreaseSpeed;
int yDirection = 1;

void Update()
{
    //turn in y Axis
    if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0)) xDifference = 0;
    else if (Input.GetMouseButton(0))
    {
        xDifference = Mathf.Abs((lastX - Input.GetAxis("Mouse X")) * 1.8f);

        if (lastX < Input.GetAxis("Mouse X"))
        {
            xDirection = -1;
            transform.Rotate(Vector3.up, -xDifference, relativeTo: Space.World);
        }

        if (lastX > Input.GetAxis("Mouse X"))
        {
            xDirection = 1;
            transform.Rotate(Vector3.up, xDifference, relativeTo: Space.World);
        }

        lastX = -Input.GetAxis("Mouse X");
    }
    else
    {
        if (xDifference > 0)
        {
            if (xDifference > 20) xDecreaseSpeed = 0.3f;
            else if (xDifference > 15) xDecreaseSpeed = 0.23f;
            else if (xDifference > 10) xDecreaseSpeed = 0.16f;
            else if (xDifference > 5) xDecreaseSpeed = 0.09f;
            else xDecreaseSpeed = 0.02f;

            xDifference -= xDecreaseSpeed;

            if (xDifference < 0) xDifference = 0;
        }
        if (xDifference < 0)
        {
            if (xDifference < 20) xDecreaseSpeed = 0.3f;
            else if (xDifference < 15) xDecreaseSpeed = 0.23f;
            else if (xDifference < 10) xDecreaseSpeed = 0.16f;
            else if (xDifference < 5) xDecreaseSpeed = 0.09f;
            else xDecreaseSpeed = 0.02f;

            xDifference += xDecreaseSpeed;

            if (xDifference > 0) xDifference = 0;
        }
        transform.Rotate(Vector3.up, xDifference * xDirection, relativeTo: Space.World);
    }

    //turn in x Axis
    if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0)) yDifference = 0;
    else if (Input.GetMouseButton(0))
    {
        yDifference = Mathf.Abs((lastY - Input.GetAxis("Mouse Y")) * 1.8f);

        if (lastY < Input.GetAxis("Mouse Y"))
        {
            yDirection = 1;
            transform.Rotate(Vector3.right, yDifference, relativeTo: Space.World);
        }

        if (lastY > Input.GetAxis("Mouse Y"))
        {
            yDirection = -1;
            transform.Rotate(Vector3.right, -yDifference, relativeTo: Space.World);
        }

        lastY = -Input.GetAxis("Mouse Y");
    }
    else
    {
        if (yDifference > 0)
        {
            if (yDifference > 20) yDecreaseSpeed = 0.3f;
            else if (yDifference > 15) yDecreaseSpeed = 0.23f;
            else if (yDifference > 10) yDecreaseSpeed = 0.16f;
            else if (yDifference > 5) yDecreaseSpeed = 0.09f;
            else yDecreaseSpeed = 0.02f;

            yDifference -= yDecreaseSpeed;

            if (yDifference < 0) yDifference = 0;
        }
        if (yDifference < 0)
        {
            if (yDifference < 20) yDecreaseSpeed = 0.3f;
            else if (yDifference < 15) yDecreaseSpeed = 0.23f;
            else if (yDifference < 10) yDecreaseSpeed = 0.16f;
            else if (yDifference < 5) yDecreaseSpeed = 0.09f;
            else yDecreaseSpeed = 0.02f;

            yDifference += yDecreaseSpeed;

            if (yDifference > 0) yDifference = 0;
        }
        transform.Rotate(Vector3.right, yDifference * yDirection, relativeTo: Space.World);
    }
}
```

I want to do something when the gameObject has rotated let's say... 90 degrees in total. Like so:

```
if (totalRotated >= 90)
{
    //do something
}
```

How do I find `totalRotated`? Thanks.

Edit: Or what if I wanted to do something when it rotates 480° in total? Is there any way?

Comment: Links can break. Include your code in your question.

Comment: 90° from what? From the starting rotation? From the last user submitted rotation?

Comment: @Draco18s sorry, it was somewhat a long code, so I didn't.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Haha, I actually found a relatively easy solution.
I added this line of code to my Update function:

```
totalRotated += (yDifference + xDifference);
```

(and I created a float named `totalRotated`) and it's working really well.

Answer (score 0):

You can rotate along the x, y, or z axis.

```
if (gameObject.transform.rotation.x == 90) // You might want to use >= to check if it is greater than 90 in this case
{
    // do something
}
```

Comment: "Use less-equals to check if it is greater?" Wot.

Comment: @Draco18s fixed it danks bud

Comment: Thanks, but what if I wanted to it as 480°?

Comment: @Qedized you would need something much more complicated.

Comment: @TannerH. I see... Thanks. I'll try it on my own then.